# Query works in workbench throws an error in node

Tags: mysql, node.js

Trying to get the id column from a database where the name column matches a variable passed through a function, so I have this

```
    const deptId = await db.query('SELECT id FROM employees_db.department WHERE `name` =  ??', [name]);
```

and get this;

> sql: 'SELECT id FROM employees_db.department WHERE `name` =  `Beauty`',

> sqlState: '42S22',

> sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'Beauty' in 'where clause'"

If I run this in workbench;

> SELECT id FROM employees_db.department WHERE `name` =  `Beauty`

it works fine and shows me the id of the relevant name column, why is the exact same query throwing an error in node? How else can I get the department id for the relevant department?

Comment: Use a single `?` (instead of `??`)

Comment: Thanks. But the moment I do this it converts name into [Object object]? I've pinpointed the issue using '??' puts 'name' into backticks like `name` is there a way to strip that in the query?

Comment: There's no reason to do that. If it's showing `[object Object]` there's something else going on. What exactly is the `name` variable?

Comment: Also, which MySQL package are you using?